# How to find the server downtime using prometheus node exporter

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

I have a few servers and I installed node exporter in all instances. But few servers are down from some time. I want to write a Prometheus query to find the instances that are down from the last X days. It shouldn't be in a reachable state in the last X days.

I tried min_over_time(up[2d])== 0.

But it didn't work for me. The above query is giving me the current unreachable server details even though it went down for one minute or more. But I want the servers/instances that are completely down in the last X days.

Any leads will be appreciable

Thanks & regards,
Bharath Kumar

Answer (score 1):

Just use `avg_over_time(up[2d]) == 0` query. It returns scrape targets, which were completely unreachable during the last 2 days.

Comment: I want to know the exact time when it was down. for ex. from the last 2 hr so and so the server was down or at 8:30 PM the server down

Comment: If you want the exact time the target was down during the last 2 days, then use the following query: `avg_over_time(up[2d])*2*24*3600` . It returns the exact time in seconds when the target was down during the last two days.